# Does Dojo allow change dom id or widgetid?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a list of dojo components and now want to allow user to remove any one of them. But this make a challenge that the array sequence is broken as one node on the chain has been destroyed. So I guess I have to manually re-assign each nodes(which after the deleted node) id and widget id.

before:

node 1 | node 2 | node 3 |....| node n |

after deletion:

node 1 |***_*__*_*___**| node 3 |....| node n |

after re-assign:

node 1 | node 2 | node 3 |....| node n-1 |

But seems these lines of code doesn't work:

```
dojo.setAttr(denomNode, "id", 'widget__record['+ index +'].id');
dojo.setAttr(denomNode, "widgetid", '_record['+ index +'].id');
```

So can dojo allow manually change id and widegetid at runtime? if not, what is the best solution to this situation?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could change the id at runtime.  Can you explain why you need the sequence to remain intact?  Can you post the code that is interacting with the array of widgets?

Comment: @Craig Swing Thanks. because the page holding the array is Jspx and controller has to get the array from the page to make further processing. So if dojo destroy a node does it mean the array sudden becomes a[0], a[2], a[3]...a[n] or it can auto adjust the index? I have the source code but it is quite abstract as Spring/Apache Tiles don't give much explicitly in source code, but I am sure the java controller is expecting the list of Doms in an array without break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation would be to hide the node so the user can't see it and have a hidden field that tracks deleted entries with a comma separated list of the ids.  On the server side you can loop through the array and make sure each entry was not deleted before processing the value.